# Double Sums in Einstein Notation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, notation

Suppose that you are given a metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ s.t. the metric is defined as $$ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}=-e^{2\phi}dt^2+\left(1-\frac{b}{r}\right)^{-1}dr^2+r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2(\theta)d\phi^2).$$ Given this metric we can calculate the Ricci tensor $R_{\mu\nu}$. The equation for the ricci tensor follows as $$R_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\lambda\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}-\partial_\mu\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\nu\lambda}+\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\lambda\sigma}\Gamma^{\sigma}_{\mu\nu}-\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\sigma}\Gamma^{\sigma}_{\nu\lambda},$$ notice that $\lambda$ and $\sigma$ are dummy indices and are being contracted, while $\mu$ and $\nu$ are our only free indices. Since we are trying to calculate $R_{\mu\nu}$ we must contract on the dummy indices.  Contraction yields $$R_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\lambda\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}-\partial_\mu\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\nu\lambda}+\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\lambda\sigma}\Gamma^{\sigma}_{\mu\nu}-\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\sigma}\Gamma^{\sigma}_{\nu\lambda}=\partial_t\Gamma^{t}_{\mu\nu}+\partial_r\Gamma^{r}_{\mu\nu}+\partial_\theta\Gamma^{\theta}_{\mu\nu}+\partial_\phi\Gamma^{\phi}_{\mu\nu}-\partial_\mu\Gamma^{t}_{\nu t}-\partial_\mu\Gamma^{r}_{\nu r}-\partial_\mu\Gamma^{\theta}_{\nu\theta}-\partial_\mu\Gamma^{\phi}_{\nu\phi}+...$$ The problem I am currently having is expanding the double sums $$\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\lambda\sigma}\Gamma^{\sigma}_{\mu\nu}$$ and $$\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\sigma}\Gamma^{\sigma}_{\nu\lambda}.$$ What exactly will these sums look like fully expanded? Im just having trouble distinguishing what values the dummies will take and in what order.

Comment: I believe you got a few signs wrong when expanding the second term (the minus sign should distribute over all of them, not only the first one)

Comment: $\lambda$ and $\sigma$ can have 4 possibilities. So there are 16 products for each of the terms mentioned.

Comment: After you do this exercise you should then calculate the $\Gamma$ terms from the Lagranian equation of motion to see why this expansion is usually not the thing to do.  Most of the terms will be zero, and the Lagrangian method only calculates the non-zero ones.

Comment: @Dan So when we contract the indices we only write the non-zero ones correct?

Comment: @aygx You don't even bother with the contractions. There will be 1 or 2 non-zero in the set of 16 from a 4x4. So you just write down the non-zero $\Gamma$ terms. You should be able to find this pretty quickly by searching on lagrangian gamma

Comment: @Dan I figured that there will each be about 2-3 non zero terms for each contraction. Regarding the non-zero ones, how do we figure out which products of christoffel symbols are non zero without directly writing the sum out and comparing all the terms to the non zero individual christoffel symbols? Furthermore, is the lagrangian method the same as the geodesic equation by letting $$L=g_{\mu\nu}\dot x^{\mu} \dot x^{\nu}$$ and applying the EL equations?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have that
$$\Gamma^\lambda_{\lambda \sigma} \Gamma^\sigma_{\mu\nu}= \Gamma^\color{red}{t}_{\color{red}{t}\color{blue}{t}} \Gamma^\color{blue}{t}_{\mu\nu}+\Gamma^\color{red}{t}_{\color{red}{t}\color{blue}{r}} \Gamma^\color{blue}{r}_{\mu\nu}+\ldots + \Gamma^\color{red}{r}_{\color{red}{r}\color{blue}{t}} \Gamma^\color{blue}{t}_{\mu\nu} + \Gamma^\color{red}{r}_{\color{red}{r}\color{blue}{r}} \Gamma^\color{blue}{r}_{\mu\nu}+\ldots$$
and
$$\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\sigma} \Gamma^\sigma_{\nu  \lambda} = \Gamma^\color{red}{t}_{\mu\color{blue}{t}}\Gamma^\color{blue}{t}_{\nu\color{red}{t}}+\Gamma^\color{red}{t}_{\mu\color{blue}{r}}\Gamma^\color{blue}{r}_{\nu\color{red}{t}}+\ldots + \Gamma^\color{red}{r}_{\mu\color{blue}{t}}\Gamma^\color{blue}{t}_{\nu\color{red}{r}}+\Gamma^\color{red}{r}_{\mu\color{blue}{r}}\Gamma^\color{blue}{r}_{\nu\color{red}{r}}+\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

I also used to also find these sorts of things confusing. It helps me to think of the general case: take a vector of $N$ numbers ${a_i}$ and a vector of $M$ numbers ${b_i}.$ So long as $N,M$ are finite, we have
$$ \sum_i \sum_j a_i b_j = \sum_j \sum_i a_i b_j \equiv \sum_{i,j} a_i b_j. $$ Where the double sum notation $\sum_{i,j}$ is used because the order of the summation does not matter (note that this is implicit in Einstein notation). You can see this by writing the matrix of numbers $T_{ij} = a_i b_j.$ The double sum is then just adding all the entries in this matrix together, and it's clear that this can be done in any order. This is essentially the discrete version of Fubini's theorem from calculus, and by thinking about the matrix $T_{ij}$ it's clear that if $N,M$ are infinite that this interchange of summation may not necessarily be true in all cases, which suggests the continuous version of Fubini's theorem.

Your specific case is just when the vectors $a,b$ are no longer vectors but objects with more indices, but everything follows the same. Indeed, the benefit of Einstein notation is that given fixed indices $\mu, \nu$ we can just assume everything is a number and the sort of higher-index structure is not important in performing the summation.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is do just do the sums one at a time. For simplicity, I'll open the expression in two spacetime dimensions $t$ and $x$, but it works quite similarly in general.

We have
$$
\Gamma^{\lambda}{}_{\mu\sigma} \Gamma^{\sigma}{}_{\nu\lambda} = \sum_{\lambda,\sigma} \Gamma^{\lambda}{}_{\mu\sigma} \Gamma^{\sigma}{}_{\nu\lambda}.
$$
Due to associativity and commutativity of addition, we can choose which sum we want to compute first. You don't need to worry about the order in which you perform the sums. Hence, we have, for example,
\begin{align}
\Gamma^{\lambda}{}_{\mu\sigma} \Gamma^{\sigma}{}_{\nu\lambda} &= \sum_{\lambda} \sum_{\sigma} \Gamma^{\lambda}{}_{\mu\sigma} \Gamma^{\sigma}{}_{\nu\lambda}, \\
&= \sum_{\lambda} \left(\Gamma^{\lambda}{}_{\mu t} \Gamma^{t}{}_{\nu\lambda} + \Gamma^{\lambda}{}_{\mu x} \Gamma^{x}{}_{\nu\lambda}\right), \\
&= \sum_{\lambda} \Gamma^{\lambda}{}_{\mu t} \Gamma^{t}{}_{\nu\lambda} + \sum_{\lambda} \Gamma^{\lambda}{}_{\mu x} \Gamma^{x}{}_{\nu\lambda}, \\
&= \left(\Gamma^{t}{}_{\mu t} \Gamma^{t}{}_{\nu t} + \Gamma^{x}{}_{\mu t} \Gamma^{t}{}_{\nu x}\right) + \left(\Gamma^{t}{}_{\mu x} \Gamma^{x}{}_{\nu t} + \Gamma^{x}{}_{\mu x} \Gamma^{x}{}_{\nu x}\right), \\
&= \Gamma^{t}{}_{\mu t} \Gamma^{t}{}_{\nu t} + \Gamma^{x}{}_{\mu t} \Gamma^{t}{}_{\nu x} + \Gamma^{t}{}_{\mu x} \Gamma^{x}{}_{\nu t} + \Gamma^{x}{}_{\mu x} \Gamma^{x}{}_{\nu x}.
\end{align}

A cool practice exercise is to perform the calculation in the opposite order ($\lambda$ first, then $\sigma$) and realize the answers are the same.